# What is the function of the に in 差別化に大変?

Tags: particle-に

アトラクション要素として、店内にメリーゴーランドでも設置したのだろう。場末の居酒屋は他店との差別化**に**大変なんだろうな。その経営努力、わからんでもない。

Hi. I know the underlined sentence means "Differentiating their izakaya restaurant from others is difficult.". And some say the bold に is a mistake, which should be が. Some say the に is a colloquialism to use -ni to introduce the aim of an endeavor for 大変だ, as in "最初はすごく理解されるのに大変だったけれど、"(I don't quite understand this explanation).

Could you please shed some light on the function of this に? Personally I don't really think it is a mistake, but I can't find this usage in my textbook ether.

Thank you.

Comment: I am assuming that 大変 here is a suru verb although it is not in the verb form. This would justify the use of ni, since it takes a adverb to modify a verb and you need ni after a noun to change it into adverb. So I would say that the ni here is just changing 差別化 from a noun to a adverb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to choose [a definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB/#jn-166083) from a dictionary, it'd be this:

> **５** 動作・作用の目的を表す。「見舞いに行く」「迎えに行く」

But it is far from enough specific for your question, I guess.

The explanation you got "to introduce the aim of an endeavor" is basically correct, that the expression implies that someone is *doing* something at the moment, and tells what condition they are in (by adjective), trying to achieve or finish what (by に).

> 先生はテストの採点に忙しい *The teacher is busy marking the tests.*
> 監督は決定力の強化に熱心だ *The manager is eager in improving scoring ability.*

The adjective has to describe a certain manner of an action, so "action-less" kind of words like mental adjectives are not allowed.

> × 私は日本語の勉強に面白い

> 場末の居酒屋は他店との差別化に大変なんだろうな。
> "I guess an izakaya in an outlying area must be desperate for differentiating itself from others."
> "I guess an izakaya in an outlying area must try the hard way to differentiate itself from others."
> "I guess an izakaya in an outlying area always struggles to differentiate itself from others."

Comment: Honestly your comment of “The adjective has to describe a certain manner of an action, so "action-less" kind of words like mental adjectives are not allowed.” describes very well why I personally find this sentence a little awkward (though understandable)... You can 熱心に強化する but you can’t 大変に差別化する (or at least it seems like a stretch).

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Yeah, it's fairly understandable to me but I can't deny that it should better be something like ～に大わらわ or ～に苦労している. (btw using 大変に as an adverb only makes it a different meaning :)

Comment: @Nanigashi Thank you! I'll correct them.

Comment: You're very welcome! And thanks as always for taking the time to write such a clear and informative answer; I always learn so much from your posts.